# How do I customize the scrollable tab in Android Studio like this?

Tags: android, tabs, customization, android-scrollable-tabs

This

[image]

contains a picture which has 'All' selected in the scrollable tab. So when an item in the tab is selected, an inverted triangle must appear as it appears in the picture below the word 'All'. How do I set that effect for an Android App in Android Studio?

Comment: Have you manage to find any solution?